# Does snap pixel trigger outside of snapchat?

Tags: javascript, snapchat

According to Snapchat:

> The 'Snap Pixel' is a piece of JavaScript code that helps you measure the cross-device impact of campaigns. With it you will be able to see how many Snapchatters take action on your website(s) after seeing your ad.

This implies that this event won't be fired/tracked if viewed outside of the Snapchat platform. But is that the case?

Testing this has been tricky and confusing, and I think indeed the case is that if my page has the snap pixel javascipt code, and I visit that page, it will fire/track that event regardless of if it's followed by the ad or if within the Snapchat environment.